# iPhone - possible to show a view from a modal view in the parent's view?

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller

Hey guys, just wondering if this one is possible

I have an app that posts to tumblr, and the posting function is within a modal view of the main view. I have a connection listener that stops displaying an activity indicator in the status bar when the app gets a response from tumblr's servers. I want to display a message saying that it was posted successfully in the main window, outside of the modal view..is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, you can add a subview to the UIWindow. In the app delegate make the window a property, if it isn't alreay. Now you can access the window with

```
((YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).window
```

Don't forget to cast, else window will give you a warning.

Adding a subview to the parentViewController while showing a modal view controller won't show it, it's behind the modal view controller.

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with the app delegate, and feel as though it is some what forbidden..could you possibly give a code example? I hate to ask you to just have it over but I get nervous when working with the appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the outside view via the `parentViewController` property on your modal view controller?

Comment: I have attempted to. The view I am trying to show is in the modal view and I have tried [self.parentViewController.view addSubView:wasPosted] but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to do this after you stopped the activity indicator? I think I have had some problems with activity indicators where they have blocked certain stuff to happen...

Comment: putting it after the activity indicator makes no difference, unfortunately.